# Imported classes not loaded properly

Tags: flash

i am trying to create a new flash movie. i am using CS4, for publishing movie -> flash 8 - AS-> 3.0 . my issue is if i publish the movie i receive the following complier errors - >

```
ActionScript 2.0 class scripts may only define class or interface constructs.
Attribute used outside class.
The class or interface 'flash.net.URLVariables' could not be loaded.
The class or interface 'flash.net.URLRequest' could not be loaded.
The class or interface 'flash.net.URLLoader' could not be loaded.
The class or interface 'flash.events.Event' could not be loaded.
The class or interface 'flash.net.URLVariables' could not be loaded.
ActionScript 2.0 class scripts may only define class or interface constructs.
The class or interface 'URLVariables' could not be loaded.
```

i am using  this code .

```
   package
{   

    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLVariables;
    import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
    import flash.events.Event;


    public class PHPData extends Object
    {

        public function send(script:String, vars:URLVariables):void
        {
            var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(script);

            req.data = vars;
            req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

            var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            loader.load(req);


            loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, _complete);
        }


        private function _complete(e:Event):void
        {
            var vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables(e.target.data);

            var i:String;
            for(i in vars)
            {
                trace(i + ": " + vars[i]);
            }

            e.target.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, _complete);
        }
    }
}
```

i checked in all forums i did not get any solution to rectify  these errors. please guide me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Flash Player 8 only supports ActionScript 2.
2. Your document is set to be ActionScript 2.

PS that class looks familiar ;P

Comment: thank you Marty Wallace , i got that class from your zipped file only. yes its working fine but if i use the same class in another document i get the following error . Flash Player 8 does not support 2.0 means then what's a way to solve this error.

Comment: All you need to do is go **File -> Publish Settings**. From here specify that you want to use Flash Player 9 or higher, and then select ActionScript 3 in the dropdown beside that.